# Shutdown mode in si4010 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, low-power, low-battery

I'm working on a project with si4010 microcontroller plus a battery and I want to save power, so I have to enable the shutdown mode. I need to wake up every 1s and do the process and then go back to the sleep state. This microcontroller works for another project with buttons so they wake it up everytime you push a button, but in my project I don't have any buttons. I just have an ADC and a field sensor.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Maybe I need a timer that when it finishes to count 1 sec wakes up the microcontroller and at the end of it will shut down and do it again.

CODE:

```
void isr_rtc (void) interrupt INTERRUPT_RTC using 1
{ 
  // Update the master time by 5 every time this isr is run.
  // clear the RTC_INT 
  RTC_CTRL &= ~M_RTC_INT;

  vSys_IncMasterTime(5);

  bIsr_DebounceCount ++;

  if ((bIsr_DebounceCount % bDebounceInterval_c) == 0)
  {
    vBsr_Service();
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: How precise this 1s interval needs to be? I mean, precise like in a watch or precise as in well it's about time to make dinner? If you are not sure maybe you can explain a bit what the micro needs to do every 1s ;)

Comment: I want this microcontroller go to sleep for 1 sec and then wake up, sample the adc and transmit data. After it go back to sleep for one sec and do it again and again..

Comment: but is this data time sensitive? I mean, can the interval be anything between 0.9 and 1.1s? Or must it be 1.000s? or maybe 1.000000s? that was my point.

Comment: no it doesn't matter

Comment: I'm sure many guys can help you if you put enough information about your project. for example you have spoken about a project. do you want to change it? Ok, now you commented. If I were you, I would send a request to it each 1sec to send data.

Comment: What's the master?

Comment: can you provide the user guide for the 8051uc that's embedded in your chip? we need to know all the peripherals it has because maybe you won't need another chip. @Roh he can't do like you say because he wants a sleep state for most of the time to save power. listening on the antenna will work but it's not quite sleeping...

Comment: ok change it. it need to wake up every one sec. Do the all process (it should take  1 sec )and then go to sleep for one sec.

Comment: https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si4010.pdf

Comment: http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN370.pdf

Comment: @VladimirCravero What's the problem!? I heve never used 8051 mcu but I can guess that he can use my trick in interrupt mode without any problem. can't he?

Comment: @Roh I assumed you meant "send a request via radio to it each second". The interrupt is the best way iff the micro supports a timer that runs while it's sleeping.

Comment: Roh what is your trick>??

Comment: idantech, please look page 95 of the AN370. the micro is equipped with a "sleep timer module" that is designed just to do what you need.

Comment: yes i know but it not working, i try to. this is my main code:

Comment: EA=0;

   time=lSleepTim_GetOneHourValue ();
  time = time / 0xe10;
  vSleepTim_SetCount(time | 0x1000000); // timer for waking up
  vSleepTim_AddTxTimeToCounter(0);
  vSys_Shutdown();
  EA=1;

Comment: @idantech I'm saying that you can send a request(via SPI or UART or other interfaces that is configured in interrupt mode) to your mcu while it's in sleep mode. after recieve the request by mcu it wakes up and reads the ADC and send the amounts to the master.

Comment: @idantech please put your codes in question not in comment.

Comment: It can't work because i work with transmitter only.

Comment: all my code? it very long..

Comment: @idantech Seems you have already tried somethings. why don't you completely explain to us all things? keep in your mind if you want to save more power, then it's better to do my trick because there is no need to use timer. if you really cannot to do mine then do everythings that vladimir said. and don't forget that if you use lower clock rate(for mcu), it will use lower power consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Use the RTC timer to wake the device at regular intervals. Silabs has usually some appnotes on how to do that on the [website](http://www.silabs.com/products/wireless/ezradio/pages/si4010.aspx).

About your code snippet:

> `vSys_Shutdown(); EA=1;`

You probably want to enable Interrupts *before* going to sleep.

Comment: yes, i know this but i'm not sure how to do it. in a code example they used this function for this interrupt :